# Why appears the error: Error In the XML document (0, 0)?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xml-serialization

I have an error in my code. I want to deserialize different `XML` files and open them in `TextBox`.
The problem I had was when I took the path of the file, I think that is where the error is, because you need an exact file path (for example):

```
FileStream FS = new FileStream("example.analy", FileMode.Open,  FileAccess.Read);
```

But I replaced it with this:

```
FileStream FS = new FileStream (openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

To read the files that were selected in openfiledialog.
This is my complete code:

```
XmlSerializer XS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Reminders.Information));

FileStream FS = new FileStream (openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Information Info = (information)XS.Deserialize();
Settings.Default.Counter++;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

The problem is that when I try to open a file, the following error appears:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error In the XML document (0, 0).'
>   Inner exception
>  XmlException: Root element Is missing.

Comment: And what is in the file being opened?

Comment: @HorusKol Do you mean the XML file?

Comment: Yes. Please post a short example of the XML file that is producing the error

Comment: @HorusKol  Do you mean that instead of using that XML Serializer I need to replace it with a XML Reader?

Comment: @HorusKol  Also, when I Try to Put a XML Reader It Shows error, I think I missing a using reference, but I dont know which Is, because I have in using reference the System.xml.Serialization enabled

Comment: Please show all code, including using statements, and an example XML, and whatever error messages you get. Also, please try the code from the example in my answer and respond with whatever errors you get there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the file steam into an XML reader that can then be serialized - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx

```
// Create an instance of the XmlSerializer specifying type and namespace.
    XmlSerializer serializer = new
    XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedItem));

    // A FileStream is needed to read the XML document.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);

    // Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
    OrderedItem i;

    // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
    i = (OrderedItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    fs.Close();
```

As far as I can see, you're trying to deserialize nothing... And nothing is not a valid XML document

Comment: This Is the XML Code Of a saved file: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Information xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Title1>My age has never made me wise</Title1>
  <Description2>Description</Description2>
  <Date3>2018-02-27T22:05:39</Date3>
  <Hour4>2018-02-27T22:05:39</Hour4>
</Information>